# Manually building Hexagonal Torus

Tags: openscad

I am interested in building a hexagonal Torus using a mesh of points?

I *think* I can start with a 2-d polygon, and then iterate 360 times (1 deg resolution) to build a complete solid.

Is this the best way to do this? What I'm really after is building wing profiles with variable cross section geometry over it's span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Your way You can do this with `polyhedron()`. Add an appropriate number of points per profile in defined order to a vector „points“, define faces by the indices of the points in a second vector „faces“ and set both vectors as parameter in `polyhedron()`, see [documentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/The_OpenSCAD_Language#polyhedron).  You can control the quality of the surface by the number of points per profile and the distance between the profiles (sectors in torus).

Here an example code:

```
// parameter:
r1 = 20;            // radius of torus
r2 = 4;         // radius of polygon/ thickness of torus
s = 360;            // sections per 360 deg
p = 6;          // points on polygon
a = 30;                 // angle of the first point on Polygon

// points on cross-section
// angle = 360*i/p + startangle, x = r2*cos(angle), y = 0, z = r2*sin(angle)
function cs_point(i) = [r1 + r2*cos(360*i/p + a), 0, r2*sin(360*i/p + a)];

// returns to the index in the points - vector the section number and the number of the point on this section
function point_index(i) = [floor(i/p), i - p*floor(i/p)];

// returns the points  x-, y-, z-coordinates by rotatating the corresponding point from crossection around the z-axis 
function iterate_cs(i) = [cs[point_index(i)[1]][0]*cos(360*floor(i/p)/s), cs[point_index(i)[1]][0]*sin(360*floor(i/p)/s), cs[point_index(i)[1]][2]];

// for every point find neighbour points to build faces, ( + p: point on the next cross-section), points ordered clockwise
// to connect point on last section to corresponding points on first section 
function item_add1(i) = i >= (s - 1)*p ? -(s)*p : 0; 
// to connect last point on section to first points on the same and the next section
function item_add2(i) = i - p*floor(i/p) >= p-1 ? -p : 0;
// build faces
function find_neighbours1(i) = [i, i + 1 + item_add2(i), i + 1 + item_add2(i) + p + item_add1(i)];
function find_neighbours2(i) = [i, i + 1 + + item_add2(i) + p + item_add1(i), i + p + item_add1(i)];

cs = [for (i = [0:p-1]) cs_point(i)];
points = [for (i = [0:s*p - 1]) iterate_cs(i)];
faces1 = [for (i = [0:s*p - 1]) find_neighbours1(i)];
faces2 = [for (i = [0:s*p - 1]) find_neighbours2(i)];
faces = concat(faces1, faces2);

polyhedron(points = points, faces = faces);
```

here the result:

[image]

Since openscad 2015-03 faces can have more than 3 points, if all points of the face are on the same plane. So in this case faces could be build in one step too.

Answer (score 0):

Are you building smth. like NACA airfoils? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NACA_airfoil

There are a few OpenSCAD designs for those floating around, see e.g. https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:898554